# CPU Usage from a file on Linux

Tags: linux, file, cpu-usage

I have to get the cpu usage on Linux from a file located on my hard drive. But after some research about it, I didn't find a proper file which informs me about the CPU usage.

The best solution would be to find the file which contains these information and updated frequently.

If you know one file which make this, it would be great, thank you.

Comment: Notice that the `/proc/` file system is *not located on your hard drive*, it is a pseudo-file system virtually managed by the kernel. Your hard disk could explode, and (assuming the kernel is still running), `/proc/` would remain available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sort of information is available under the `/proc` filesystem. See [`man proc`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html).

In particular:

- `/proc/loadavg` gives load averages;
- `/proc/stat` gives information on the amount of time the system spent in user/kernel mode, etc (thanks @Mat!)
- `/proc/[pid]/stat` contains information on CPU times for the given process.

`man proc` will give further details.

Comment: `/proc/stat` is also interesting.

Comment: Notice that it is not a *disk* file, it is a *pseudo-file* existing only thru the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `/proc/loadavg` for determining the load from a file.